# How can I make inline r script visible in RMarkdown report?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose that the command isn't important enough to have it on the separate line, But I still want it to be visible along the result, I know there is `` ` r inlinestr` `` in R Markdown, but it I can't pass `echo=T` to it. I want the result to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use backticks, which would give you the monospace font, but not the gray background shading:

> f. There are `sum(is.na(df$Height)) =` `r sum(is.na(df$Height))` missing Height values.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is what I use right now. I don't have a problem with font/shading, I just didn't want to have the same thing twice.

Comment: Ah, well, I don't know of a way to avoid repeating the code.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this question that I attempted to answer about two years ago and thought of a way to get both the code and its evaluated output in a single inline statement. We just need a helper function. Below is an example. The code is entered as a text string and the function returns both the code and the result of evaluating the code:

````
---
title: "RMarkdown teaching demo"
author: "whoever"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
fnc = function(expr) {
  paste(expr, " = ", eval(parse(text=expr)))
}

# Add some missing values
iris$Sepal.Length[c(3,5,10)] = NA
```

f. There are `r fnc("sum(is.na(iris$Sepal.Length))")` missing height values.
````

Below is the output.

---

[image]

---

It works, but there are two issues. First, the code is not in monospace font. Second, the code is not highlighted with a gray background.

I thought that I could get monospace font with the latex `\texttt{}` tag.

````
```{r}
fnc = function(expr) {
  paste("\\texttt{", expr, " = ", eval(parse(text=expr)), "}", sep="")
}
```
````

This appears to return the desired string when run interactively (`"\\texttt{sum(is.na(iris$Sepal.Length)) = 3}"`), but throws the following error when I try to knit the document:

> ```
> ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
> <recently read> \egroup
>
> l.163 ...texttt{sum(is.na(iris$Sepal.Length)) = 3}
> ```

I thought I could get highlighting with the `\hl{}` tag (which also requires `\usepackage{color, soul}` in the latex header):

````
```{r}
fnc = function(expr) {
  paste("\\hl{", expr, " = ", eval(parse(text=expr)), "}", sep="")
}
```
````

However, once again, this throws an error:

> ```
> ! Argument of \SOUL@addmath has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> l.161 ...re \hl{sum(is.na(iris$Sepal.Length)) = 3}
> ```

Both `texttt{}` and `\hl{}` work without a problem when used with regular text inside an `rmarkdown` document.

So, I'm not sure how to get the monospace font or highlighted text, but at least this takes a step toward code + evaluated code from a single inline R statement. Hopefully, someone with more knowledge of computing on the language and outputting latex markup can provide more insight into how to get this to work as desired.